# How can I remove duplicate entries with a function in Google Sheets, keeping the row with the highest value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some social data coming through Supermetrics into a Google Sheet. It's set to update the posts so that I get the most recent/accurate metric numbers, but it's bringing in duplicate rows: multiple rows for the same post, but with different metric numbers.

I want to query the data to produce a sheet with only one post with the highest value in one of the metric columns.

Here's an example sheet (editable) of what I have and what I want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kRyZA-8UpL8GG4xocertQlgwGDtDcXLR5ZZKOaZcAaM/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried using both a query and the sortn function (`=SORTN(data!A2:O, 9^9, 2, 1, 1)`), and the sortn function works to remove duplicates, but it keeps only the first one (seemingly). I need to keep the highest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sortn(sort(A3:E8,5,0),9^9,2,4,1)
```

[image]